# Changing the Bold icon in tinyMCE editor

Tags: css, tinymce

I want to change the bold icon's text in the tinyMCE editor to "Bold" instead of "B"!
is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible.
for example for simple theme you must change image to :

[image]

if you add image you must change bold width and other element background-position offset ,
for this you must change UI css of this theme for example :

original:

```
/* Theme */
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_bold {background-position:0 0;}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_italic {background-position:-60px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_underline {background-position:-140px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_strikethrough {background-position:-120px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_undo {background-position:-160px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_redo {background-position:-100px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_cleanup {background-position:-40px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_insertunorderedlist {background-position:-20px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_insertorderedlist {background-position:-80px 0}
```

edited:

```
/* Theme */
.mce_bold{width: 40px !important;}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_bold {background-position:0 0;width:40px !important;}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_italic {background-position:-90px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_underline {background-position:-170px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_strikethrough {background-position:-150px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_undo {background-position:-190px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_redo {background-position:-130px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_cleanup {background-position:-70px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_insertunorderedlist {background-position:-50px 0}
.defaultSimpleSkin span.mce_insertorderedlist {background-position:-110px 0}
```

I add space to image for this , I force add 30px to all background-position for fix this new space added.
after than you can enjoy form that :D

if you what say me i attach edited file.

Comment: How about if I want to use text instead of an image icon, is it still possible?

Comment: Yes, of curse , change background to none , and use `content` in `:before` or ':after`.